# Is there any way to use "like" operator during oracle table partitioning

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I am using Oracle 11g database and I have 45 million records. I want to partition the table, but if it's possible for partitioning to support the `like` operator then it will be much helpful for me.

In my table one column is `URI`, and for that column I want to use the `like` operator during partition so that it can help during insertion, because it contains different type of uris such as `model://a/b` or `list://a/b`.

I want something like:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    URI varchar2(20);
)
PARTITION BY LIST ( URI )
      (PARTITION part_mod VALUES (like 'model://%'),
       PARTITION part_list VALUES (like 'list://%'),
       PARTITION part_def VALUES (default)
       );
```

I tried using [Virtual Column-Based Partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm#CACFEGDG) but didn't get any success. Partitions were created, but during insertion no data is going into corresponding partitions; everything is going into `part_def`.

So is it possible to use the `like` operator to partition a table in oracle database?

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: @miracle i have already mentioned in the post i.e. Oracle 11g database.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual column partitioning:

```
create table table_name (
    uri varchar2(20),
    part as (
      case 
        when uri like 'model://%' then 'mod'
        when uri like 'list://%' then 'list'
        else 'def'
      end
    )
)
partition by list (part) (
  partition part_mod values ('mod'),
  partition part_list values ('list'),
  partition part_def values ('def')
);
```

Seems to work:

```
insert into table_name (uri) values ('model://abc');
insert into table_name (uri) values ('list://abc');
insert into table_name (uri) values ('test://abc');

select * from table_name partition (part_mod);
select * from table_name partition (part_list);
select * from table_name partition (part_def);
```

Inserted rows are returned from correct partitions.

Comment: thanks i can use as a last option but if it is possible without adding any extra column in the table then it will be much  easy for me to implement.